# forEach: run function when finish

Tags: javascript, mongodb, foreach

I selected some documents from `MongoDB`.

I wanted to:

1. Go over these documents.
2. Insert the id of each document into an array: `ids`
3. When `ids` array contains the ids of all of the documents, run a function.

I found a way to do that:

```
let ids = []

myDb.collection('myCol')
  .find({"name":"a"})
  .forEach(
      (feed) => {
         ids.push(feed._id)
      }, 
      () => done(ids)
  )

function done(ids) {
    // do something
}
```

Unfortunately, I don't know why does it work: `() => done(ids)`.

I know this sintax, but why can I send this function to forEach method?

I tried to find some references but found nothing.

As I read, `forEach` gets only one parameter: one function that will be run on each object of the array.

So why the second function is acceptable? and how it runs when the forEach is ends and not on each object?

Explanation with a reference will help me alot.

Comment: do you use mongo native driver?

Comment: Because there is no function overloading in javascript, javascript functions do not care if you pass them 0 parameters or 100 parameters - it will just ignore any additional parameters that are not defined. If you want to call the done function after your forEach is done, place it lexically after the foreach() and you'll be fine

Comment: @Svabael, I use:
var mongodb = require('mongodb');
var MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;

Comment: It's not [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) or [`forEach`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.forEach/) but [`forEach`](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Cursor.html#forEach)?

Comment: @Bergi, I guess you are right!

Thank you very much (I can accept it when you answer this question)

Comment: @mhodges, I will check it. thanks!

Comment: To be honest I'm not sure what the difference between the second and the third method is.

Comment: one gets one argument (only a function) and the second one gets two arguments: function (that will be run on each object) and a callback to run when the loop ends. Am I right?

Comment: Note that `.find()` returns a MongoDB `cursor`, not a Javascript array.